# Not triggering http request inside then

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is the function on the page

```
this.productProvider.getproductlist().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This is the function in my provider

```
getproductlist(){   
    this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
      return this.http.get(this.baseAppUrl+'/getproductlist?token='+val);
    });

  }
```

Error:
property subscribe does not exist on type void

If I try this

```
this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
  this.token = val;
});
return this.http.get(this.baseAppUrl+'/getproductlist?token='+this.token);
```

I will not get property subscribe does not exist on type void error but token value is null.

Comment: try returning the function and check

Comment: @Mahesh Jadhav, Thanks for the reply, Error: Property 'getproductlist' does not on type productProvider.

Comment: remove subscribe and try adding a then after you return the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code use mergeMap and fromPromise(to create observable from promise)  from rxjs library:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';


getproductlist(): Observable<any> {   
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token')).mergeMap((val) => {
    return this.http.get(this.baseAppUrl+'/getproductlist?token='+val);
  });
}
```

Comment: more concise and elegant than my solution, i will keep it in mind for future implementations, i vote.

Comment: Thank you @Marco Barbero

Answer (score 0):

When I implement component interaction via a service I use the Observer pattern, in this case the scope of the service instance is the notification from a component (Publisher) and other componentents (Subscriber).

**mycomponent.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyComponentService{
    // Observable 
    private sampleObservable = new Subject<boolean>();
    // Observable boolean streams
    sampleSubscriber = this.sampleObservable.asObservable();
    // Event for notification from publisher to subscriber
    sampleEventChanged(value:boolean)
    {
        this.sampleObservable.next();
    }
}
```

In the component who wants to notify all subscribers a change of its state:

**mycomponent-publisher.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './mycomponent.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-control-publisher',
  template: `
  <h2>This is the publisher control</h2>
  <button (click)="announce()">Announce to subscriber</button>
  `,
  providers: [MyService]
})

export class MyControlPublisherComponent 
{
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  announce() 
  {
    this.myService.sampleEventChanged(true);
  }
}
```

In the subscriber component who want to get the notification.

**mycomponent-subscriber.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './mycomponent.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-my-control-subscriber',
 template: `
 <h2>This is the subscriber control</h2>
 `,
})

export class MyControlSubscriberComponent 
{
  // Subscriptions
  private componentSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) 
  {
    // Subscription of the notifications
    this.componentSubscription= this.myService.sampleSubscriber.subscribe(value =>
    {
      // Put the code for manage the notification here
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    // Release subscription to avoid memory leaks when the component is destroyed
    this.componentSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In your case getproductlist should be declared as observable

```
// Observable resources
private getProductListObservable = new Subject<any>();
// Observable streams
getproductlistSubscriber = this.getProductListObservable.asObservable();

getproductlist ()
{
    this.getProductListObservable.next(this.http.get(this.baseAppUrl+'/getproductlist?token='+val));  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried your solution still getting same error. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. @Marco

Comment: I think that I have understand. This is a pattern that I use mirrored and that works correctly.I have changed the implementation logic.